# NullPointerException on taking a picture and save as URI

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I'm following [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954) blog post to add this feature onto my app where I can take a picture then save the picture data as a Uri for further functions. But I'm getting an error when I try to open the camera intent.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I suspect there is something wrong with the `file_paths.xml` but I double checked there is nothing wrong. I've done some research on different ways of saving images through like `FileProvider` but most of it doesn't work for me either.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

**MainActivity**

```
private void openCameraIntent() {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        //Create a file to store the image
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,                                                         com.example.camerapplication.provider", photoFile);
            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent,
                    REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Glide.with(this).load(imageFilePath).into(image);
        // TODO:Use Image Uri for further functions
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

// ... Other elements and then
// Within application scope

<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
    </meta-data>
</provider>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.cameraapplication/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**EDITED** 
changed to proper path="Android/data/com.example.cameraapplication/files/Pictures"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your package name is `com.example.cameraapplicationfiles`?

I think it should be `Android/data/com.example.cameraapplication/files/Pictures`

if not try something like this.

for the authorities use full string name
`android:authorities="com.myCameraDemo.app".`

ans for the file_paths.xml `<external-path name="site_images" path="Android/data/com.myCameraDemo.app/files/Pictures" />`

if it works then you know where the problem is.

Comment: Yup i forgot to add "/' onto my path directory and i have tried changing based on what u suggested unfortunately it is still giving me the same error

Comment: do not use this. try your package name in manifest file `com.myCameraDemo.app`

Comment: Do you mean `com.cameraapplication.app` ? So in my authorities would be `android:authorities="com.cameraapplication.app.provider"`?

Comment: What is your app package name. ?

Comment: `com.example.cameraapplication`

Comment: Then use it `android:authorities="com.example.cameraapplication` and `<external-path name="site_images" path="Android/data/com.example.cameraapplication/files/Pictures" />`

Comment: Yupp, that solved it, I think is because in my MainActivity i forgot to change one of the line that why it couldn't work. Thanks mate

Comment: Great!. I also had same frustration when im using `file_paths.xml` and all first time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the external path should be like the following. Considering your application package name is `com.example.cameraapplication`.

```
<external-path
    name="documents"
    path="Android/data/com.example.cameraapplication/files/Pictures" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that your application ID is not `com.example.android`.

In your code, you have:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.provider", photoFile);
```

This means that the authority needs to be `com.example.android.provider`.

In your manifest, you have:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

Therefore, `${applicationId}` is not `com.example.android`.

Your `android:authorities` value is fine, but you need your `getUriForFile()` call to match. A typical way of doing that is:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", photoFile);
```